# Python conditional operator 'if else' not equal 'and or'

Tags: python, python-2.7, conditional-operator

I think below two function result will be same, but it is not.

```
def fib2(n):
  return n and n < 2 or fib2(n-1) + fib2(n-2)

def fib3(m):
  return m if m < 2 else fib3(m-1) + fib3(m-2)
```

When argument value is 4, fib2's output is 7, fib3's output is 3. Why this situation happen?
I don't know about this.
My Python version is 2.7.9 and os is osX 10.11.1

Comment: Your first function is equivalent to: `(n and n < 2) or fib2(n-1) + fib2(n-2)`

Comment: You could try debugging without using the ternary statement, and use a visual debugger like: http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: The answer is http://stackoverflow.com/a/394887/2301450. Or maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/10314837/2301450

Comment: @DavidZemens Thank you very much! I don't know operator priority of python. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for everybody help me. I will delete this duplicated question soon.

Comment: @user3867387: there's no reason to delete this question though. Duplicates are useful, and good duplicates are very useful.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to be more verbose and write your functions like this:

```
def fib2(n):
    ret = n and n < 2 or fib2(n-1) + fib2(n-2)
    print "fib2({}) = {}".format(n, ret)
    return ret

print fib2(4)

def fib3(m):
    ret = m if m < 2 else fib3(m-1) + fib3(m-2)
    print "fib3({}) = {}".format(m, ret)
    return ret

print fib3(4)
```

It appears that `fib2` tries to add boolean values to numbers, and that's why it's not correct. `fib3` handles only numbers and is correct. But notice that it's not a recommended way to calculate Fibonacci numbers! If you try fib3(1000) it will run infinitely. It's better to start from 0 and 1 upwards, and not use recursion to calculate Fibonacci numbers.

I wrote a short function that calculates Fibonacci number #n for you:

```
def fib4(n):
    a = 0
    b = 1
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        a, b = (b, a + b)
    return a

print fib4(0)
print fib4(1)
print fib4(2)
print fib4(3)
print fib4(4)
print fib4(1000)
```

Notice it also works for `n==1000`.

Comment: The problem is actually only that for `n = 2` it is `0 and 0 < 2 or fib2(-1) + fib2(-2)`. Since `0` is falseish, `(0 and 0 < 2) == 0` so the result is `0 or fib2(-1) + fib2(-2)`. Since `0` is still falseish, the result is `fib2(-1) + fib2(-2)`.

Comment: @poke Run this program and you will see that `fib2(1)` is True, and so are `fib2(-1)` and `fib2(-2)`. All the other numbers are arbitrary, because they are results of adding True with an integer. They don't make any sense. But of course you can define such a function if it makes sense for you! Or actually, it seems that True is equal to 1 so `fib2(n)` is actually `fib3(n+2)` (because `True + True` is 2 and `True + 2` is 3.

Comment: Yes, I know, but you can calculate with `True`. It’s `1`! (Know that `bool` is actually a subtype of `int`) And `fib2(1)` should be `1` so it giving `True` is actually an *“acceptable”* result. The real problem is that it breaks for `n = 0` (mistyped that in the comment above) which causes the big problems. If it was working for `0`, you wouldn’t notice the weird result of `True` for `fib2(1)` if you didn’t ask for exactly `fib2(1)`. (btw. this was not criticism of your answer—your answer is just fine—it was just some additional information)

Comment: @poke Yes, I noticed. Please see my updated comment. Only `fib2(1)`, `fib2(-1)` and `fib2(-2)` are defined and `True`, all the other calls call to recursion. So from `n==2` on (not including `n==1`), this is Fibonacci sequence for `n+2`. Anyway, one should never write Python code that adds numbers to Boolean values.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's a new Fibonacci sequence, starting with 2 and 1.