# Python what do 'and/or' mean in expression, and what does `(not i%2)` test?

Tags: python, ternary-operator, idioms, or-operator, and-operator

I am learning python list comprehension and saw a usage and I couldn't find explanation in official document.

```
>>>[(not i%2)*'a' or str(i) for i in range(10)]
>>>['a', '1', 'a', '3', 'a', '5', 'a', '7', 'a', '9']
```

I am trying to abstract this usage in this way:

```
[statement1 or statement2 for i in range(10)]
```

and if statement1 is evaluated as false, then use statement 2, am I right?

I also discover that if I run the following command:

```
>>> [(not i%2)*'a' and str(i) for i in range(10)]
```

The output would be:

```
>>> ['0', '', '2', '', '4', '', '6', '', '8', '']
```

How should I understand these?

Comment: This is almost surely a duplicate of existing Q&A.

Comment: And `(not i%2)` is an idiom to check if an integer is odd; there are at least 6 existing questions on that. To be more clear, we would declare a predicate function `is_odd(n)`.

Comment: `true_value and cond or false_value` is the old [Python pre-2.5 idiom for implementing a ternary operator (?: or ifelse)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator). The [newer idiom is `true_value if cond else false_value`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/394814/202229). It's irrelevant whether this is in a list-comprehension or elsewhere. Anyway, this has been asked many times before. Also: ["Python conditional operator 'if else' not equal 'and or'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33780600/python-conditional-operator-if-else-not-equal-and-or)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's right.  The weird part is the first expression:

> (not i%2)*'a'

If i is odd, then this evaluates to 'a'; if even, it's False.  This is a blatant abuse (a.k.a. expert trick) of boolean definition in Python.

If you imagine **True** as 1 and **False** as 0, it makes sense.  If the product is 0, the **or** operator takes it as **False**.

This also takes advantage of expression short-circuiting: if the left element of the **or** is **True**, then the right one isn't evaluated at all, and that left element becomes the expression's value.

Similarly, in your later example, the **and** short-circuit works the other way: if the left element is **False**, then it becomes the result; otherwise, the right element becomes the result.

Comment: "otherwise, the right element becomes the result."
Why in this case we only take the right element as the result?

Comment: Because George Boole proved as a lemma that **True and x** must be **x** for all **x**.  Similarly, **False or x** must be **x** for all **x**.

Answer (score 0):

Here or return the first value that can be evaluated as `True` .
So if the first statement return value can be evaluated as True, just use it or search for the next value.
Try to add more 'or'

```
 [(not i%3)*'a' or (not i%5)*'b'  or 'c' for i in range(10)]
 => ['a', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'a']
```

And returns the last value only if all the values can be evaluated to `True`

Answer (score 0):

The statement explained:

`not i%2`: `i % 2` evaluates to `0` for even integers, `1` for odd integers. `not` will result in a boolean that negates the following expression. `not 1` => `False`, and `not 0` => `True`.

`(True)*'a'` => `1 * 'a'` => `'a'`

`(False)*'a'` =>  `0 * 'a'` => `''`

`''`, when cast to boolean, is evaluated as `False`

`False or str(i)` => `str(i)`

Answer (score 0):

If you turn that into a list of tuples (with both conditions included), it is easier to see what is happening:

```
>>> [((not i%2)*'a', str(i)) for i in range(10)]
[('a', '0'), ('', '1'), ('a', '2'), ('', '3'), ('a', '4'), ('', '5'), ('a', '6'), ('', '7'), ('a', '8'), ('', '9')]
```

Any odd value of i produces `''` which is `False` in a Python sense. The `or` then evaluates the right hand side and returns that rather than a left hand side:

```
>>> 'LH' or 'RH'
'LH'
>>> '' or 'RH'
'RH'
```

It is *better* stated as a conditional expression because it is easier to read:

```
>>> ['a' if i%2==0 else str(i) for i in range(10)]
['a', '1', 'a', '3', 'a', '5', 'a', '7', 'a', '9']
```